# Is there a way to limit peer to peer twilio programmable call only for two people?

Tags: twilio, twilio-video

I have a requirement to limit twilio video programmable call only between two people now people can join the room up to ten but I want to limit this for two only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Twilio Peer-to-Peer setup you can limit the number of participants up to 10. You can find it at Programmable Video -->Rooms-->Setting at the middle.
https://www.twilio.com/console/video/configure

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you [create an access token for Twilio Video](https://www.twilio.com/docs/iam/access-tokens?code-sample=code-creating-an-access-token-video-2&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x) you can set the room name in the token. Users with a token with a room name set can only join that room. You can use this to only create tokens for your users that allow them to join the rooms they are allowed to enter and you can then limit your rooms to two people only that way.

Let me know if that helps at all.